# Acesso a um valor de um array json no Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, laravel

Estou trabalhando num projeto em Laravel. Estou fazendo um função de busca dinâmica utilizando Ajax e Json.

Função no controller:

```
public static function busca_ajax()    
    {    
        $query = Input::get('query');    
        $resultados = Produto::busca($query);        
        foreach($resultados as $produto) {
            $imagem = $produto->imagens->first();    
            if(!$imagem) {    
                $imagem = $produto->base->imagens->first();    
                if(!$imagem) {    
                    $imagem = '';    
                }    
            }    
            $produto->imagem = $imagem;
        }    
        return Response::json($resultados);         
    }
```

A função é de buscar produtos. Ela busca um produto a partir do conteudo digitado pelo usuário. Depois para cada um desses produtos ela busca a imagem dele: primeiro se o produto tiver variações; se não, encontrar, busca no produto base; se não encontrar, adiciona "";

A função encontra os produtos, mas acontece algum erro ao adicionar as imagens no array json, por que quando tento pegar o valor no retorno do ajax, dá um valor "undefined".

Função javascript completa:

```
    function checkprod(val) {

    if (val.length >= 3) {

        $('.loading').fadeIn();

        var request = $.ajax({

                url: baseurl+"/produtos/ajax_busca_produto",

                type: "POST",

                data: { query: val },

                dataType: "json"

            });



            request.done(function(data) {


                x = '<br><br> <h6>Clique em um produto para selecioná-lo.</h6><table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered table-hovers"><thead><tr>';

                x += '<th width="30%">-</th><th>Nome</th>';

                x += '</tr></thead><tbody>';

                for (var i in data){


                    //navego pelas chaves do array como um for

                    x += '<tr style="cursor: pointer;" class="hover-effect">';

                    x += '<td onClick="completeFieldProduct('+data[i].id+',\''+data[i].nome_completo+'\')"><img src="'+baseurl+'/../uploads/medium/'+data[i].imagem+'" style="width:70px" /></td>';
                    x += '<td>'+data[i]+'</td>';

                    x += '<td onClick="completeFieldProduct('+data[i].id+',\''+data[i].nome_completo+'\')">'+data[i].nome_completo+'</td>';

                    x += '</tr>';

                }

                x += '</tbody></table>';

                $("#complete").html(x);

                $('.loading').fadeOut();

            });     

    }

    else {

        $("#complete").html('');

    }

}
```

Método imagens():

```
public function imagens()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('ProdutoImagem', 'imageable');
    }
```

Obs: O projeto já está pronto e não fui que fiz. Só estou tentando consertar essa função.

Comment: Cadê o código JS ? Fez alguma coisa ?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com a função completa